# Transmission web client: strange charasters in file names

Tags: 12.04, transmission

I have nas:

- Operating system: Ubuntu Linux 12.04.1
- Kernel and CPU: Linux 3.2.0-34-generic on x86_64
- Transmission 2.51 (13280)

On all operating system (browser Chrome) web client Transmission in file names after point of becoming a symbol

> "&#8203 ;" (without space)
>
> "The.&#8203 ;Big.&#8203 ;Bang.&#8203 ;Theory.&#8203 ;S06E05.&#8203 ;720p.&#8203 ;WEB-DL‌​.&#8203 ;Rus.&#8203 ;Eng.&#8203 ;mkv 810.7 MB of 810.7 MB (100%)" (without space)

How to remove these characters?

Comment: FYI That is the unicode for ZERO. `this character is intended for line break control; it has no width, but its presence between two characters does not prevent increased letter spacing in justification` http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm

Comment: But why browser output this in the plain text?
Samlpe:
The.&#8203;Big.&#8203;Bang.&#8203;Theory.&#8203;S06E05.&#8203;720p.&#8203;WEB-DL.&#8203;Rus.&#8203;Eng.&#8203;mkv
810.7 MB of 810.7 MB (100%)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix /usr/share/transmission/web/javascript/file-row.js:

line 140:

`name = name.replace(/([\/_\.])/g, "$1&#8203 ;");` (without space before ";")

replaced

```
name = name.replace(/([\/_\.])/g, "$1");
```

Next, clear browser cache.

Answer (score 3):

The original line 140 in `/usr/share/transmission/web/javascript/file-row.js` tries to insert zero width spaces in the file name, so it would break nicely on long filenames.

```
name = name.replace(/([\/_\.])/g, "$1&#8203;");
```

The problem is that when it is set, HTML escape sequences are not interpreted, but actually made visible for the end user. This can be solved by using javascript escape sequences instead.

Replace line 140 with:

```
name = name.replace(/([\/_\.])/g, "$1\u200B");
```

This achieves the original goal.